# Data duplication, can it be an unavoidable practice in this example?

Tags: java, design-patterns, programming-practices, inheritance, code-smell

Say I have different employees of type `Employee` stored in a list inside a class `SubCase`.

```
public class SubCase{
    protected ArrayList<Employee> employees;
    ...
}
```

`SubCase` represents a part of a project where the employees work on.
They do have a fixed specific role in the project, but that role is inside
another class `Project`. Project knows about `SubCase` but it's a uniderectional relationship.

Normally, we don't need to know the Role of the users at SubCase level, and therefore, we have built the whole application with this in mind and it is now rather difficult to obtain the specific Role a user has using the SubCase class,  but in one subclass of Subcase, it is important to know which of the users of a subcase has a FinancialExpert-Role.

Would it be a problem if I made a separate private variable:

```
public class SubCaseExtension extends SubCase{
    private User financialExpert;
}
```

in which the `financialExpert` can be saved? Using this, it would be easy to know which user is the Financial Expert, but it would form duplicate code because the employee that is a financialExpert will also be added to the `ArrayList` of employees.

Can the duplicate data in this case be justified?

Comment: I don't see the code duplication.

Comment: Well, the FinancialExpert has to be added also to the ArrayList for other procesing-methods. With the duplicate code, I mean that the financialExpert will be inside the ArrayList aswell as inside the private variable.

Comment: Is what you are asking: if I have a smelly design, will my code smell too?

Comment: What type is private variable financialExpert and how does it make any of the employees stored in the array list a finantial expert?

Comment: Why doesn't `Employee` know its role?

Comment: I think that the question as it is now is not very clear.

Comment: @CPerkins  I guess because the an employee can play different roles in different projects.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova then OP has to choose: refactor or live with the smell.

Comment: @CPerkins Projects or "subcases" should have a `HashMap<Employee,Role>` .

Comment: Whoops forgot the type of privateExpert. The Employee doesn't know it's Role because that information is much more needed in the project-class.

Comment: The employee had indeed a different role in different projects

Comment: @CPerkins, Projects has such hashmap, but it has to be available in SubCase and SubCaseExtension also. And Project only know about SubCase and SubCaseExtension, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have - almost (see below) - no "data duplication", since what you actually deal with is a reference to the same object twice, not with a copy of an object.

If you would have to deal with the role of an employer within a subcase, on a regular basis, the solution suggested by @TulainsCórdova might be fine, however, since you wrote

> Normally, we don't need to know the Role of the users at SubCase level

so I guess exchanging `ArrayList<Employee>` by something more general just to deal with a rare edge case looks to me like overengineering for your situation. So your own suggested solution is a IMHO good approach, when you care for some details.

Adding the `financialExpert` variable in a subclass, even if it is only a reference, introduces some kind of redundancy, because you must make sure `financialExpert` will hold one element of the corresponding `employees` list (and not a completely different `Employee` object).

If this becomes a problem or not depends on how the `employees` list is initialized and manipulated. You need either to make sure the `financialExpert` does not get removed from this list accidentally at a later point in time, or you need to make sure your program can deal with that situation in a robust manner. For example, if `SubCase` objects (or at least the part which changes the `employees` list) are designed in an immutable manner, they are only initialized once, which makes it easy to guarantee the two variables won't get out of sync.

Comment: The (for the sake of giving an example) premise *"we don't normally ask women their age"* doesn't mean you have to create a `Woman` class with no `getAge()` method. Just let the app not call `getAge()` on a `Person` object when `getGender().equals("FEMALE")`.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova: the problem I see is you suggest to exchange one container by a different, more complex one, for one very specific case, where the majority of cases does not need that container. Looks to me like unneccessary overgeneralization, as long as the OP does not find out he has more cases for storing employees roles per subcase. Maybe he has, then it is good solution.

Comment: Implemented it like this and it works like a charm and seems the most suitable solution. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is that you replace:

```
protected ArrayList<Employee> employees;
```

with

```
protected HashMap<Employee,Role> employees;
```

..in projects and "SubCases".

Than way you will always know the role an Employee plays in a project.

Some refactoring will be needed. I think that way no special duplication of code will be needed.

**EDIT:** I don't suggest Role being a property of Employee since I guess an Employee can participate in different projects playing different roles.

Answer to this comment:

> @CPerkins, Projects has such hashmap, but it has to be available in
>   SubCase and SubCaseExtension also. And Project only know about SubCase
>   and SubCaseExtension, but not the other way around.

As Subcases would also have the HashMap (as I recommended above), let the Project add the pertinent key/value pairs to the inner class via a method `addEmployeeWithRole(Employee e, Role r);` in SubCase. **No data dup here because objects are passed by reference in Java.**

Answer (score 0):

Its fine, as long as you just have a pointer to the Employee. ie

```
public class Subcase
{
    protected ArrayList<Employee> employees;
    private string financialExportId;

    private User financialExpert 
    {
        get 
        {
            return employees.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Id == financialExportId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what if a person can play more than one role?  Do we automatically assume that anyone who is in a project and has financial expert role is indeed the financial expert for that case?  What if there are two financial experts on the case: then we randomly pick one as the expert?

Comment: edited to allow for mutiple roles

Comment: edited to allow specific choice of employee